# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl . Dont understand how to fix this

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, apollo-client

I have a Java spring boot project where I am mixing kotlin. Though I am stuck with this runtime exception. Which I do not understand why it happens and how to solve this

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReferenceImpl.<init>(int, java.lang.Class, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int)'
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollectorKt$emitFun$1.<init>(SafeCollector.kt) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.4.jar:na]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollectorKt$emitFun$1.<clinit>(SafeCollector.kt) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.4.jar:na]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollectorKt.<clinit>(SafeCollector.kt:15) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.4.jar:na]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.emit(SafeCollector.kt:87) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.4.jar:na]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.emit(SafeCollector.kt:66) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.HttpNetworkTransport$execute$1.invokeSuspend(HttpNetworkTransport.kt:83) ~[apollo-runtime-jvm-3.7.4.jar:3.7.4]
    at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.HttpNetworkTransport$execute$1.invoke(HttpNetworkTransport.kt) ~[apollo-runtime-jvm-3.7.4.jar:3.7.4]
    at com.apollographql.apollo3.network.http.HttpNetworkTransport$execute$1.invoke(HttpNetworkTransport.kt) ~[apollo-runtime-jvm-3.7.4.jar:3.7.4]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely(Builders.kt:61) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.4.jar:na]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect(Flow.kt:230) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.4.jar:na]
```

Happens for the following code

```kotlin
 val response = runBlocking {
        apolloClient.mutation(
          UpdateCuratedCollectionMutation(
            input = curatedCollectionInput,
            version = collection.updatedAt.toEpochSecond()
          )
        ).execute()
    }
```

My dependencies are following

```
springBootVersion = '2.7.4'
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.8.10"
id "com.apollographql.apollo3" version "3.7.4"
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.lombok' version '1.8.10'
id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '5.3.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10'
implementation "com.apollographql.apollo3:apollo-runtime:3.7.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here mentioned https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin/issues/4748

Basically I was using lightstep-tracer-jre-bundle library which was causing an issue as it was using old kotlin stdlib. Suggestion was to move to lightstep-tracer-jre